# Drag drop files behaviour from external hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-yosemite

I want it to work like the OS partition. If I drag a file from external HDD to my OS HDD I want the file to get removed from the external HDD. Is that possible?

Comment: @grgarside I'd say not a dupe, opposite behaviour. On the same drive move is normal behaviour, needs opt to copy. This is across drives, normal is to copy, add Cmd to Move.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know, but the same principles applies, toggling between move/copy in Finder.

Comment: @grgarside I agree the principle is the same, but the key to achieve it is not necessarily intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  whilst dragging, it will Move instead of Copy

Comment: Thank you. That is not what I exactly wanted but it is way better than nothing.